# Using JSON File as an Array in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I've been having trouble converting a .json file into an array object in NodeJS,

This is my **JSON**:

```
{
    "cat": {
      "nani": "meow"
    },
    "dog": {
      "nani": "woof"
    }
}
```

**index.js:**

```js
const array = require('../../data/usershops.json');
var shop = array[0].nani
return shop;
```

The output in `console is`:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'nani' of undefined

It actually returns a value if I used this:

```
array["cat"].nani // => "meow"
```

How can I get the index `key`?

Comment: you don't have an array in your json, you have just an object there that's why trying to access by index it will not work.

Comment: @V.Sambor Thanks for replying but how do I go about making it into an array in my json?

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check how to do it.

Comment: [JSON](https://json.org) is a **text** representation of some data structure. Because it is text, it cannot be an array. In order to use it one needs to parse it and get back a data structure similar to the one used to create the JSON. That data structure can be an object or an array but it can even be a primitive data type (string, number, boolean etc). Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to get the data structure then process it as you need.

Comment: `const array = require('../../data/usershops.json');` -- `require()` knows how to parse JSON files and it gets you back an object. There isn't any array here. Consequently attempting to get `array[0]` produces an error. Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to extract only the values from an object. It ignores the keys and returns the array you need.

Comment: @axiac Hey could you like use the answer button? Apparently it worked, and I'd really like to mark yours as a solution! :D

Comment: I wrote it as an answer. Please read it carefully and do not skip the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`require()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) does the JSON parsing for you and returns an object.

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get an array that contains only the values of this object (and ignore the keys):

```
const data = require('../../data/usershops.json');
const arr = Object.values(data)

console.log(arr);
// [ { nani: 'meow' }, { nani: 'woof' } ]
```

*But please be aware that the order of keys/values in an object is not determined and this means the order of values in the array returned by `Object.values()` might not always be the one you expect.

Unless you iterate over the array and use all the values in on operation that does not depend on their order, I recommend you don't use an object this way.*

Comment: and how does this solve the index problem ? If he wants to refer to the first one as cat, object values does not assure the order... This answer is ok only if he does not care about the index

Comment: @V.Sambor Have you read the entire answer? Or only its first sentence?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = {
    "cat": {
      "nani": "meow"
    },
    "dog": {
      "nani": "woof"
    }
};

let array = Object.entries(data).map(([key,value])=>value);

console.log(array[0].nani);
```

Comment: I kind of want to use a JSON file instead of creating an array within the javascript file itself :(

Comment: There is no need to reinvent the wheel. [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) does exactly the same as your code.

Comment: @RinYazuki You can manipulate the object from a JSON file within the JS file. If you wish to use the JSON object as an array directly, you would have to update the JSON file itself.

Comment: @axiac , yes i know there is ```Object.values``` for values and ```Object.keys``` for keys too! The point is to show him/her how Objects can convert to array in JS.

Comment: @YazukiRin you can access JSON object or a specific key using ```require``` ```JSON``` file directly, or ```import``` if using ```BABEL```.

Comment: e.g : ```let MyKey = require('../myfile.json')['Mykey']``` or ```import {MyKey} from './myfile.json'``` if using ```BABEL```